# Magnific Popup auto scrolls body content

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

I have [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) installed on this [website](http://bit.ly/1A3x4qe).

Every time I click a thumbnail to launch the lightbox, the body content in the background scrolls down slightly. Is there a way I can stop this from happening?

I have a feeling that the lightbox script is somehow interfering with my scroll to top code:

```
    // Magnific Popup open inline content
    $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
        type:'inline',
        midClick: true
    });

    // Magnific Popup open iframe content
    $('.vimeolink').magnificPopup({
        type: 'iframe',
    });

    // Smooth scrolling - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    // Scroll to top - http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-an-animated-scroll-to-top-with-jquery
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
        }
    });

    // Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]')` matches the images that are clicked, for instance `<a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-183">`. So yeah, when you click an image, not only the popup shows up, but the page scrolls to the hash in the URL, in that case `a#projects`.

You can differentiate `<a>` for anchors and `<a>` for images by adding a class, for instance :

```
<a class="scroller" href="#whatever"></a>

<a class="open-popup-link" href="#popup-183">
```

Now target them using their class :

```
$('a.scroller').click(function() { /* scrolling stuff */ }
```

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. Do know if there's a work around for this?

Comment: Sure, I have updated my answer. Just give them a class.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using [Featherlight](http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/). This plugin doesn't use the href attribute in a link to display the content, so you won't have that issue. It's also easier to use and their docs are better (IMO).